# How to include auto-complete feature for added xml namespace?

Tags: android-studio

I'm using the design support library for my app. When using some of the included design support views in my xml layout resource files, I have to declare:

"xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

in the root layout in order to declare the attributes for these views (e.g. app:popupTheme attribute for the support Toolbar).

Android studio usually has a helper box that appears after typing the android namespace that presents me all the attribute available, but it doesn't give me that for the "app" namespace. How can I enable this feature?

Answer (score 1):

If you start typing `appNs`, there should be a suggestion to autocomplete typing the app namespace (`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto`).